# How can I user the standard speech recognise activity on Android Wear 2 without user interaction?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an Android Wear 1.5 application and I want to upgrade it support the new Android Wear 2.0 system.

Everything has been migrated/updated but I'm having a strange behaviour of the standard speech recognise activity: on v1.5 it does not require user interaction, on v2.0 it requires user to accept the text just recognized.

I'm launching the activity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Prompt");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I've tried `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE` but it seems it doesn't work as expected, it complains about not finding an activity to fulfil the request (no standard activities for this action?).

Can you help me finding a way to launch a standard speech recognizer activity that does not require user interaction?

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by "requires user to accept the text", "does not require user interaction", etc. In general, it depends on the speech recognition provider, how the UI is implemented. This implementation is not part of Android Wear, it's a separate app. If you want to avoid the UI altogether, then you should call the recognizer via the SpeechRecognizer service.

Comment: Thank you @Kaarel. I thought the implementation of the speech provider was, by default, part of Android Wear and overridable by other application.